# how to read javascript code which have vague function and variable names

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I was trying to read a js code of a chrome extension but couldn't because of the way it was written. All the functions are only one letter and the same goes for the variables. different functions have the same variable names, i.e. only one letter, and many functions have the same name too. Though I think it may be converted code from the original one by some means.
I want to know how this code has been generated and if is there any other way to read the code than just brute forcing my way through it.

```
function T(e) {
        var t = "";
        return (t = Array.isArray(e) ? chrome.i18n.getMessage(e[0], e.splice(1)) : chrome.i18n.getMessage(e)).length ? t : "{no translation}"
    }
    const A = document.documentElement,
        N = new ExtStorageManager(null, function (a) {
            N.onUpdate("settings.enabled", n => {
                n ? e() : t()
            }).onUpdate("settings.changeIcon", e => {
                e && N.get("settings.enabled") ? v(k.playerActive) : v()
            }).onUpdate("processExtensionReload", e => {
                e && n()
            }), a.settings.enabled && e(), chrome.runtime.sendMessage("registerTab"), window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
                !B && chrome.runtime.sendMessage("unregisterTab")
            }), chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(o), S()
        });
    (new ExtAutoInject).then(n);
    let q = null,
        I = null,
        L = null,
        D = null,
        x = null,
        C = null,
        M = null,
        O = null,
        B = !1;
    const $ = {
            playbackFailed: !1,
            fetchFailed: !1
        },
        k = {
            videoElement: null,
            playerActive: !1,
            playerFit: !1,
            pageUrl: location.href
        };
```

Comment: As you have already guessed, it is not very easy to understand the code. The purpose, however, is not to hide the intentions of the code itself, but to make it shorter which would speed up the download and parsing times (this however is not the case with extensions that are downloaded only during updates and saved locally).
Sometimes the developer shares the source code on GitHub or similar platforms. You just have to ask the developer and \ or owner directly. You may be luckier than you think.

Comment: This is called minification, it's a standard part of the modern JS toolchain, it improves parsing/compiling time in extensions just as much as it helps in web sites. Assuming there's no source code you need to learn about reverse-engineering JS. In short, you would use a proper IDE like VSCode where you can look up variables, find usages, jump to definitions and so on.